# не работают Google Maps в бета версии приложения через скачивание в PlayMarket, но работают напрямую

Tags: android, google-maps-api, google-maps, карты

Не знаю в чем проблема,тестирую бету скачивая ее с PlayMarket, в андроид проекте для дебага есть есть google_maps_api.xml один файл , для релиза другой в которых у меня одинаковые ключи `AIzaSy*****euA`, и как я прочитал для релиза должен быть сгенерирована другая SHA1, но имена пакетов и сам ключ могут не различаться в самой api консоли, просто генерируется другая контрольная сумма SHA-1 и вписывается, но вот загвоздка в том, что при скачивании с плеймаркета гугл карты не работают, но вот когда ставишь напрямую apk-release файл, то всё работает.

Кто-то сталкивался с таким?

[image: signingReport]

Answer (score 2):

Такое может случиться по следующим причинам:

1. отсутствует разрешение интернет (но в этом случае вредил)
2. Не вписан верный SHA-1 для release сборки. Попробуйте повторить процедуру.

2.1 Слева в меню Android Studio нажмите на **Build Variants**, поменяйте debug на **release**.

2.2 Справа меню Gradle. Выберите раздел :app/Tasks/Android/signingreport и скопируйте SHA-1 для release сборки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image]

Comment: Добавил в тело письма скрин, в котором почти всё, что было в SigningReport, но куда копировать,илил откуда копировать SHA1, я к сожалению так и не нашел.

debug на release поменял, карты работают) но сейчас опять залью на ПлейМаркет снова чувствую не будет работать)

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, Гугл сам подписывает приложения.
Надо было отсюда сертификат подписи sha 1
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вставить в google api
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Гугл не подписывает, это студия подписывает, а гугл лишь отпечатки показывает